# Where to find Soundcloud API track ID

Tags: sdk, soundcloud

I can't find it in the documentation, or on a track-page itself `https://soundcloud.com/jakechudnow/shona`

I used a demo: `SC.get("/tracks/293", function(track){...`

Which works, but where do I get that track number? This doesn't help either: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks

And nothing is explained about how to go about finding these tracks: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

> getting the latest track of a group

*the* lastest track of *a group*? which group? how do we define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that SC offers the resolve-endpoint

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve